# Is "Customizable" a valid English word?

Tags: adjectives, dictionaries

Is the word "**Customizable**" a valid English word? Every time I write that word, the spell checker underlines it, and it suggests using "Customization" or "Customize". I'm not a native English speaker, but that word exists in online dictionaries so I wonder why the spell checker underlines it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary in its revision of March 2012 defines it as:

> That may be customized; able to be changed to suit the requirements of
>   the user. Frequently with reference to computer software and hardware.

The earliest citation is from 1960. If that definition of *customizable* suits your purpose, then there’s no reason why you shouldn’t use it.

Comment: Wow! Strange, this word is used a lot in our everyday life and i assumed that it is included in the spell checker, i can't understand how that thing does not underline new words like Google or Facebook, but it underlines costumizable, I assumed that the checker knows more than me and i rely on it a lot especially when typing a formal email, i spent like 2 hours trying to understand what i did wrong! Stupid computers! Or maybe it's me who's stupid, relying on a computer! the era of smart phones and stupid people! Merci beaucoup

Comment: @Fischer You miss-spelled the word here. No need to fault spell-check, there are words that are flagged to alert you on possible unintended errors. Some words may not have been included the spell-check dictionary -- you can always add the word of your choice to the custom dictionary after checking authentic sources.

Comment: @Kris it's not my responsibilities to add English words, besides you can't add exception everywhere

Comment: It's one own responsibility to add whatever words one may need/like to one's custom dictionary. See the FAQ/Help in spell-check.

Comment: @Kris How do you suggest I add it to this comment? Because it underlines it here. Besides, if it is a word that is in most English dictionaries these days then I blame spell check.

Comment: @Ryan The spell checker here is your browser spell checker, to add a word, you can simply right click on the word and you should find an option says something like: "Add to dictionary" or something similar, at least it works on desktop chrome.